# Problem with iterating through mysql table after one loop

Tags: php

I have 2 tables. First one is `categories` and the second is `items`.
I need my script to print to .txt file the name of the category and underneath it category items with matching 'category_id'. My code uses first `while` loop to iterate through the categories and second to iterate through items. Everything works fine until we get to second `while` loop, because then values become empty.

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query_for_categories)) {
    fwrite($fp, $row2["category_name"].PHP_EOL);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_for_items)) {
        if ($row2['id_category_from_category'] == $row['id_category_from_items']) {
            fwrite($fp, $row["item_name"].PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, fix syntax errors before posting the coding here and use proper punctuation in your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my punctuation but I'm not a native English speaker, will apply more weight to it in the future

Comment: There is still one `;` missing in the 3rd line and an extra `}` in the 5th line

Comment: What kind of IDE are you using that it is not highlighting the syntax errors for you? Please use a proper IDE with a code formatter and code analyser e.g. VS Code.

Comment: using sublime, the code was ok but I had to cut out some parts so I overlooked some mistakes

Comment: What is the problem? You haven't explained what this is actually doing vs what you expect it to do

Comment: Have you done any debugging yourself? Is the `if` statement ever true?

Comment: As I said, i have 2 tables: categories and items i want script to print category name and under this all items names with same "category_id" as category like so: category_one:item_one,item_two category_two: item_three, item_four (just an example), and the problem is that after first run of first while values become empty for "items"

Comment: Yeah if statement works fine, first category have items it should have when i run script but the rest of categories are printed without items and from what i discovered (just by printing value of "items"  after every run of first while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first iteration of the outer while loop, you will have fetched all the rows from `$query_for_categories`. There will be no more rows to fetch from that query on subsequent iterations of the outer while loop.

You can fetch them all into an array first

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_for_items)) {
    $items[] = $row;
}
```

Then use the rows from that array instead of a while ... fetch loop.

```
while ($category = mysqli_fetch_array($query_for_categories)) {
    fwrite($fp, $category["category_name"].PHP_EOL);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if ($category['id_category_from_category'] == $item['id_category_from_items']) {
            fwrite($fp, $item["item_name"].PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

---

It does seem like you could probably do this with one query using a join, though. I'd recommend checking into that instead of doing it this way. Based on the column names in your code, the query would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT c.category_name, i.item_name
FROM categories c
  LEFT JOIN items i on c.id_category_from_category = i.id_category_from_items
ORDER BY c.category_name, i.item_name
```

Then you could print the items with categories in one loop like this:

```
$previous_category = null;

while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    // each time category changes, output the new category name
    if ($item['category_name'] != $previous_category) {
        fwrite($fp, $item["category_name"].PHP_EOL);

        // then current category becomes previous category
        $previous_category = $item['category_name'];
    }
    fwrite($fp, $item["item_name"].PHP_EOL);
}
```

I do wonder how you can tell which of the lines in the file are items and which are categories, though. Maybe you should output some kind of indicator for that?

Comment: Thank you I will try this immediately

Comment: It did the work now everything works fine, I am really grateful for your help it also was a huge lesson for me. Now my code is 1/2 smaller. Again I mightily appreciate your help and everyone elses for pointing me my faults